# partitioning - for dual boot win7/linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, partitioning

I have a quick question for the partitioning for this set up.

Requirmenets I think are: set NTFS partition for windows >12ish gb, ntfs partition for ubuntu.

What I want is small/small as possible ubuntu install, and rest will be for win7. I install like this to still access HD etc if/when windows stuffs up.

I always have people saying to create a partition x2 memory size and call swap. I dont know what it is or if its even used if you create it. Do I bother? or do I just create small ntfs partition for ubuntu (anyone know the min size?), install win7 in the rest... sort out grub from livecd once done.

Answer (score 1):

Just setup a dual boot from existing Vista to Win7/Ubuntu 9.10 with help of this article: http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony This worked out very well. Pay special attention to assigning the mount point and the swap file definition.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you

[Here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/partitioning)

It describes what partitions are used for...the swap is normally 1.5 to 2 times the size of your ram, as mentioned on there...its also nice to have /home on its own to, once again I think its explained on that page

Hope that helps